# C++ threads add code after function call

Tags: c++, multithreading

i have something like this piece of code

```
class Someclass{
int somevalue;
void somefunction(int& arg1, bool& arg2);    
}

int main(){
Someclass someobject;
int something;
bool maybe;

thread t(...);
}
```

I want to make a thread that calls the 'someobject's void with the arguments int 'something' and bool 'maybe'. In addition to that the thread also should cout the int of the class after executing the function. I cannot write the cout directly into the member function because I need the cout to be optional.

I have come to this

```
thread t([&someobject] () {
    someobject.somefunction(something, maybe);
    cout << Value: << someobject.somevalue << endl;
});
```

Is this the right way to do this or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that looks like a good way to do it.

Don't forget to capture `something` and `maybe`, and watch out for synchronisation (maybe capture them by value?).

Answer (score 0):

You need some mechanism to synchronize. You need to make sure that `void somefunction` has already finished all works about `somevalue` before you output the `somevalue`, otherwise you may output the value before `somefunction`. Even worse, if somevalue cannot guarantee atomic operation, you may output something strange.